# systemctl command not working in RHEL 6

Tags: centos, rhel, services

On RHEL 7 or CentOS 7, the systemctl or systemd command works fine. I know it won't work in RHEL 6 or CentOS 6. Can you tell me the alternative command for starting/stopping a service, for example: `systemctl start iptables.service`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In earlier versions of RHEL use the `service` command as explained in the [documentation here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s3-services-running-running).

```
# service service_name start
```

Therefore, in your case:

```
# service iptables start
```

You can replace `start` with `restart`, `stop`, `status`.

List all services with:

```
# service --status-all
```

Comment: Note: there still is a compatibility script `service` in RHEL7, which can actually do more than systemctl does, so for the moment, it's a safer bet on all supported versions.

Answer (score 0):

rhel 6 and centos 6 are using upstart, not systemd. SysV (service and chkconfig) is also still supported.

Check documentation of `initctl` and files in /etc/init/

Answer (score 0):

RHEL6 and CENTOS 6 were using `service` command to manage system services. From RHEL7 onwards `systemctl` is used to manage system services.